# Clear shopping cart event in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Can anyone tell me what is the right event to trigger when the user click clear shopping cart  button.I want to remove some information on the basis of that event.Currently I am storing information on add to cart event using observer .Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event in 1.7.0.2

```
// app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php:389
Mage_Checkout_CartController::updatePostAction()

// app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php:441
Mage_Checkout_CartController::_emptyShoppingCart()

// app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php:489
Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::truncate()

// app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php:837
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::removeAllItems()
```

You can listen on `checkout_cart_save_before` and check wether the cart is empty and your setting is set, if yes, remove it.

Comment: Small comment, `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::removeAllItems()` method has been introduced in Magento 1.7 and is absent in earlier versions.

Answer (score 4):

i recently implemented this in a custom module.

```
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_updatePost
```

this event get calls exactly when pressed clear cart.

in the observer you can check if the method was called for empty cart:

`$post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('update_cart_action'); // get value
 if ($post == 'empty_cart') {
     // perform logic
     $quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote(); //quote
     $allQuoteItems = $quote->getAllItems(); // quote items
     // do code
 }`

Hope it helps.

Comment: How did you get access to the products / quote items in the cart?

Comment: you can get them, i've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Universal method**

config.xml

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_save_after>
        <observers>
            <module_model_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>module/observer</class>
                <method>salesQuoteSaveAfter</method>
            </module_model_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_save_after>
</events>
```

Observer.php

```
public function salesQuoteSaveAfter($observer)
{
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote */
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    if($quote->getItemsCount() == 0) {
        // your code
    }
}
```